# Problem scraping Bet365 Odds w/ Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been writing a program to scrape odds from betting sites using Python and Selenium. When I request the Bot to get the sites, most of the sites get loaded, but not Bet365. The browser keeps loading forever and the screen stay grey. I guess they blocked bots from accessing the site. Any suggestions to fix it?
Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "/users/jpnas/Documents/botNBA/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.bet365.com")
```

Comment: Can you be abit more specific on what you mean by blocking ? What error messages are you getting ? And what data are you trying to extract specifically ?

Comment: Hmm, you wanna live and prematch odds?

Comment: What I mean by blocking is that the browser keeps loading forever and the screen stay grey.

Comment: I just want the prematch odds.

Comment: This worked in driver 91: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65062205/python-undetected-chromebrowser-suddenly-not-working-on-bet365-com