# Python undetected-chromebrowser suddenly not working on bet365.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

While using selenium for python to scrape bet365, I learned that I needed to use (successfully) [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

This code worked like a charm up until just a few days ago

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://bet365.com')
```

Now, however, when using this I get this in my browser

[image]

and my page is never returned.

Recently chrome appears to have updated me to version 87 so I tried downloading and using the newest chromedriver that is recommended for my version of chrome. This did not change matters.

I then decided to revert back to my previous version of chrome and use the chromedriver that corresponds to that version. This also did not change matters.

I have also tried to change my viewport and add a fake user agent. Still nothing.

I read somewhere to try this option

```
options=uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows")
```

but my issue was still unresolved.

So now I'm here asking: is there is anything I can do to successfully pull up bet365.com using `undetected_chromedriver`?

NOTE: this is not related to [Chrome driver for Selenium stuck in grey screen on bet365 site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794511/chrome-driver-for-selenium-stuck-in-grey-screen-on-bet365-site)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it was that post originally that led me to using `undetected-chromedriver` in the first place. That actually resolved my issue originally. I feel like something else is going on but I don't know what it is. Also note that I'm not getting a grey screen, but a white one.

Comment: Exactly! Stop marking it as duplicate. Same happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053339/bet365-detects-selenium-chromedriver

Comment: I'm amazed by how quickly it is to render a question as a duplicate. Surely it's too easy to close questions. Please re-open.

Comment: @MattCremeens Moving forward if you feel your dup-closed question wasn't a duplicate, once you edit the question you need to add the username appending the `@` sign, so the user who closed the question is notified. I've reopened the question as mistakenly I have dup marked it earlier.

Comment: OK @DebanjanB. Thanks. For some reason the name of the closer didn't appear for me, but maybe I just missed it. Thanks for re-opening.

Comment: this question really helped me, where can I find how ```undetected_chromedriver ``` works?

Comment: @coderoftheday click on the link in the question or go here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So late last night I stumbled on the solution. Thankfully using `undetected-chromedriver` still works provided you modify the actual chromedriver.exe file. I didn't even know you could edit an exe file but I simply opened it in Notepad++ (it looks like scrambled gobbily gook) and did a find and replace

cdc_ to xyz_

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Matt, does this method still work for you? Thanks!

Comment: @apascualb no. bet365 has made a recent change that makes this solution insufficient. My email is in my profile. Please email me and I'll respond.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me. You may try to custom the chromedriver and specify a proxy.

```
undetected_chromedriver.install(
    executable_path='c:/users/user1/chromedriver.exe',
)

opts = uc.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue with this

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://bet365.com')
```

Comment: This code did the trick. The "cdc_" solution was not working in 91 version of chromedriver. thks